# removing 2x button resizing the app screen size in air project

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, air, flashdevelop

hey guys i'm currently developing a game that will run in iPad and iPhone using AIR with flash develop. and one of my task is to remove the 2x button on the lower right corner of the  screen when run in iPad. can anyone there know the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase your app is compiled only for iPhone.

You have two options:

1. Make the app universal - then it runs on both iPhones and iPads.
2. Make another different app for iPad.

There are pros and cons for both options.
Read more here in Apple's documentation: [Creating a Universal App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24)